# Some issue with date formatter: MM/DD/YY not working as expected

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying following piece of code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY");
    Date d=formatter.parse("05/12/15");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Expected output: `05/12/15`

Actual output: `12/362/15`

Comment: Your first reaction should be to check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and make sure your pattern does what you think it does (hint: it doesn't).

Comment: http://metadata-training-centre.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-simpledateformat.html

Answer (score 3):

Learn details, [SimpleDateFormat](http://metadata-training-centre.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-simpledateformat.html). For your format, use `MM/dd/yy`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using uppercase D which is the day of the year.
Use lower case d for day of the month. The year y should be lower case as well i.e `"MM/dd/yy"` .

See [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

The used pattern is wrong. As stated [here](http://metadata-training-centre.blogspot.it/2014/06/using-simpledateformat.html) `DD` returns the "day in year" whereas you need `dd` for the "day in month". Hence, the correct code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```